# How to remove double quotes surrounding the text while importing a CSV file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have data which resembles the following:

```
"D.STEIN","DS","01","ALTRES","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","APCASH","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","APINH","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","APINV","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","APMISC","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","APPCHK","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","APWLNK","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","ARCOM","TTTTTTFFTT" 
"D.STEIN","DS","01","ARINV","TTTTTTFFTT"
```

I've used a Flat File Source Editor to load the data. What is the easiest way to remove all of the double quotes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Further searching revealed that I should use the **`Text Qualifier`** on the `General` Tab of the Flat File Source.

Flat file content when viewed in a Notepad++. **`CRLF`** denotes that the lines end with `Carriage Return` and `Line Feed`.

[image: Flat file in Notepad++]

On the flat file connection manager, enter the double quotes in the **`Text qualifier`** text box.

[image: General tab of the flat file connection manager]

Once the text qualifier is set, the data would be parsed correctly and displayed as shown below:

[image: Columns tab of the flat file connection manager]

Comment: Thanks! great stuff. I lost time trying to fix this myself.

Comment: This fixes the " in the data. How about removing it from column names as I don't see Text Qualifier property in the columns and manually removing " from the advanced tab takes a lot of time.

Comment: @PrakashTripathi, just click the "Reset Columns" button.

Answer (score 0):

while loading CSV with double quotes and comma there is one limitation that extra double quotes has been added and the data also enclosed with the double quotes you can check in the preview of source file.
So, add the derived column task and give the below expression:-

(REPLACE(REPLACE(**RIGHT(SUBSTRING(TRIM(COL2),1,LEN(COL2) - 1),LEN(COL2) - 2)**," ","@"),"\"\"","\""),"@"," ")

the bold part removes the data enclosed with double quotes.

Try this and do let me know if this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
substring([column 5], 2,(len([column 5])-2) )
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather use the following statement....

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnName, '""', '[YourOwnuniqueString]'), '"', ''), '[YourOwnuniqueString]', '"')
```

**Note:** please make sure your `YourOwnuniqueString` should be unique and not used any where in the columns as data. E.x: `SQL@RT2#myCode` -*It is case sensitive*-